# To prove given function is constant function

Tags: functions

Suppose $f,g,h$ are functions from the set of positive real numbers into itself satisfying
$$f(x)g(y)=h\left(\sqrt {x^2+y^2} \right)\ \ \forall \ x,y\in (0,\infty )$$
Show that the three functions $\frac {f(x)}{g(x)},\frac{g(x)}{h(x)},\frac{h(x)}{f(x)}$ are all constants.
I only succeed in to show $f/g$ is constant function i,e, i got $f(x)=g(x)$.
Anyone can help me to prove that $g/h$ is constant.

Comment: It is better if you show how you got $ f(x)=g(x)$.

Comment: @Derivative divide $f(x)g(y)$ by $f(y)g(x)$ we will get $f(x)=g(y))$ for all x,y

Comment: That is not exactly correct.

Comment: @Derivative can you explain it

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: Are you sure that here $x,y$ cannot be $0$?

Comment: @Derivative yes the question is absloutely correct and this question was asked in M.sc entrance exam

Comment: Why not use that $f(x)g(0) = h(x)$ and $f(0)g(y) = h(y)$?

Comment: Mattos: $x,y$ cannot be $0$

Answer (score 2):

So, by dividing by $f(y)g(x)$, you get $f(x)/g(x)=f(y)/g(y)$ for all positive $x,y$. So then obviously $f/g$ is constant.

Ok, here is my try: $f(x)g(1)=h(\sqrt{x^2+1})$ and $f(x)g(\sqrt{2})=h(\sqrt{x^2+2})=f(\sqrt{x^2+1})g(1)$.

So,$f(x)g(\sqrt{2})=f(\sqrt{x^2+1})g(1)$. i.e. $f(x)=f(\sqrt{x^2+1})g(1)/g(\sqrt{2})$. Hence $f(\sqrt{x^2+1})/h(\sqrt{x^2+1})=g(\sqrt{2})/g(1)^2$. Now change variable $y=\sqrt{x^2+1}$. But we are done only for $y>1$.

Comment: i also did the same thing. But can u prove h/g is constant

Comment: But you don't get $f=g$. That is what I wanted to point out.

Comment: sorry it was $f=kg$ where is constant. The main aim is to prove h/g is constant

Comment: See my edited answer now.

Comment: you can change 1 and 2 to any positive number and then the equality hold for all y

Comment: @novavita But not intependently, one must be the double of the other...

Answer (score 2):

Assume that you have two positive numbers $u$ and $v$ and select $c$ smaller than both. Then you have that you can write $u=\sqrt{x^2+c^2}$ and $v=\sqrt{y^2+c^2}$ for some positive $x$ and $y$

$$f(x)g(c) = h\left(\sqrt{x^2+c^2}\right)$$
$$f(x)g(c\sqrt2) = h\left(\sqrt{x^2+2c^2}\right) =
   f\left(\sqrt{x^2+c^2}\right)g(c)$$

So

$${h(u)\over f(u)} = {h\left(\sqrt{x^2+c^2}\right)\over f\left(\sqrt{x^2+c^2}\right)} = {f(x)g(c)\over f(x)g(c\sqrt2)/g(c)} = g(c)^2/g(\sqrt c)$$

In similar way you get

$${h(v)\over f(v)} = {g(c)^2 \over \sqrt c} = {h(u)\over f(v)}$$

That is $h(v)/f(v) = h(u)/f(u)$ for any positive $u$ and $v$ which means that $h/f$ is constant.

Comment: 0 is not positive real number and it us not included in our domain. If 0 is included then everyone can solve it

Comment: @GirishKumarChandora Yes, but now I don't use $0$ anymore...